# Signal protocol questions

Tags: java, encryption

Good day! I have several questions about Signal protocol using.

I have a small, basic chat and want to encrypt messages (end-to-end). I want to try Signal as you see, but I wand to keep my server-side implementation.

From what I saw - all the work begins with creating public keys and sending them to the server. Then, when Alice wants to write to Bob a message she asks server to send her a  PreKeyBundle. After that all message exchange is just like in SessionBuilderTest at github repo.

The main questions are:

- if I get  PreKeyBundle, when will it expire?
- When should I ask for another PreKeyBundle? When I ask for PreKeyBundle
- does server deletes that key from PreKeyStore, so no one can use it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone uses **Bob** and **Alice** so I'll do the same

The pre key bundle is built from:

1. Registration ID
2. Identity public key
3. Signed pre key (public key and a signature)
4. Ephemeral pre key (public key)

Both **Alice** and **Bob** start by generating keys.
Both send to the server what they've created (only the public part of the keys, of course).
Now let's assume **Bob** wants to message **Alice**.
**Bob** asks the server for a *signed pre key bundle*.
The server sends the fixed keys (identity and signed), signature, and one of the unsigned pre keys.
It then disposes of the pre key - it is never used again, so **Bob** has a key that is unique for him, and will never expire.
**Bob** can now use the bundle to create a shared secret and send it to **Alice**, starting a session between the two using ratchet keys that change for each message.

### So to answer your questions:

- You ask for a pre key bundle when you want to start a session
- Your bundle does not expire
- The server deletes the pre key (a part of the bundle) and will never use it again

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have already found key scheme from some University and digged into the source code, so this question is done. Thanks again. I'll mark your answer as correct